How to add notification message in outlook compose window with office js add-in with action button
I want to add notification message in outlook compose window. On this make 2 buttons one is Add and second one is Dismiss. when click on add button do call an API in commonds js. Is it possibale. i have attach one sample image can you please check it and let me know if anything possiable
here is sample image like in this manage subscription and unsubcribe i want here dismiss and add button
i am trying to make office add-in in this when new mail window and add recipient then triggr function that will show notificaiton message in this same i have attached image up

Simple example: replace Icon.80x80 with your icon name which is in the manifest
  const id = "InsightMessageNotification";

      const itemId = Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
      const details = {
        type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InsightMessage,
        message: "This is an insight notification with id = " + id,
        icon: "icon1",
        actions: [
          {
            actionText: "Open insight",
            actionType: Office.MailboxEnums.ActionType.ShowTaskPane,
            // Identify whether the current mail item is in read or compose mode to set the appropriate commandId value.
            commandId: (itemId == undefined ? "PG.HelpCommand.Compose" : "PG.HelpCommand.Read"),
            contextData: { a: "aValue", b: "bValue" }
          }
        ]
      };

      Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.addAsync(id, details, handleResult);

Currently, only one action per notification message is supported (as documented in the NotificationMessageDetails.actions description. However, you could add a second notification to give your users another option.
it looks like this

